# difference in probability picking cards one after the other and simultaneously

Tags: probability, combinations

12 cards numbered 1 to 12 are mixed inside an urn. Two cards (x, y) are picked successively and without replacement. What is the probability that the sum x+y is an odd number?

Well, in order for us to have an odd number, one of the numbers x or y must be even and the other odd. However, when I tried to solve this problem by using

C(6,1)xC(6,1)/C(12,1)xC(11,1) this gave me the wrong answer. When trying 
C(6,1)xC(6,1)/C(12,2) this gave the correct answer. Shouldn't both of them be equal? What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: The standard mathematical notation for what you write as $C(6,1)$ is $\binom61$ etc. I think your first answer is the probability the first card is odd, and the second is even, which is half the probability you seek.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\C}[2]{\mathop{^{#1}\mathbf C_{#2}}} \dfrac{\C 6 1 \C 6 1}{\C {12}1\C {11}1}$ is the probability for picking an odd card and *then* an even card.   It is also the probability for picking an even card and *then* and odd card.

Who cares about the order?   I do not; do you?

The probability for picking and odd and even card *in any order* is therefore: $\dfrac{2 \C 6 1 \C 6 1}{\C {12}1\C {11}1}$

By some strange quirk of how numbers work, this is also $\dfrac{\C 6 1 \C 6 1}{\C {12}2}$

The probability for selecting one from six odd cards and one from six even cards when selecting two from twelve cards in any order (without bias or replacement).

Comment: but the notion that the order doesn't matter shouldn't already have been taken into account, given that we are using the formula for combinations?

Comment: Using combinations in a formula does not guarantee order is not considered anywhere.  @Erick3434

Comment: so the simple act of multiplying both of them already imposes an order over them? I always thought that multiplying the probability of A occurring and B occurring simply gave you the probability of A and B occurring, not a specific order of them

Answer (score 0):

You have two types of cards. Odd = {1,3,5,7,9,11}, of which there are 6.
There are also 6 even cards labeled {2,4,6,8,10,12}. Lets say you pick an odd card first the probability of this was 6/12 as there were 6 possible cards and 12 possible total cards. You must then pick an even card of which there are 6, but only 11 cards in total remain so you have a 6/11 chance of drawing an even card given since an odd card was already drawn. You then multiply these two numbers together to get the probability of drawing an odd card and then an even card. 6/12 * 6/11 = 36/132. However, you can also draw an even card first, you'll find the probabilities are the same if you reverse the order so you can just multiply the current probability by 2. P[odd and even] = P[odd|even]P[even] + P[even|odd]P[odd] = 2*(36/132) = 36/66.

Answer (score 0):

${6\choose 1}{6\choose 1}/{12\choose 2}$ is indeed correct. The problem with your original attempt is that ${12\choose 1}{11\choose 1}=12*11$ counts how to pick two cards with an order on them. If you pick $5$ then $7$, that method counts it once, and if you pick $7$ then $5$, that method counts it again, but those should be considered the same draw, since ${6\choose 1}{6\choose 1}$ does not impose an order on the cards drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Picking cards successively without replacememt is covered by hypergeometric formula which is exactly the same as the second one that you have mentioned.  This kind of explains the rationale what the other responder has given you in a formulaic fashion.  In the response, he has two components, the first one being odd and the second one being even and the other being the opposite, together gives 2 times of anyone which is 6.  In the hypergeometric formula this is achieved by expanding the denominator and the two goes to the numerator to give the effect of the other responder's result.